# What does C.H. Edwards mean by "orientation" in the development of Stokes's theorem in n dimensions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, graph-theory, stokes-theorem, exterior-derivative

---

Edit: I am inclined to believe that the overall answer is going to be: it doesn't matter which sense we call positively oriented as long as we are consistent during our traversal.

---

The following is from C.H. Edwards's Advanced Calculus of Several Variables, Section V6 *Stokes' Theorem*.  I'm pretty sure there are some typos in the indexing.  The quoted material appears contiguously in the book.  I have interleaved my text.

> So we start with the unit cube
> \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{I}^{k}= & \left\{ \left(x_{1},\dots,x_{k}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{k}:\text{each }x_{i}\in\left[0,1\right]\right\} 
> \end{align*}
> in $\mathbb{R}^{k}.$  Its boundary $\partial\mathcal{I}^{k}$ is the
> set of all those points $\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{k}\right)\in\mathcal{I}^{k}$
> for which one of the $k$ coordinates is either $0$ or $1;$ that
> is, $\partial\mathcal{I}^{k}$ is the union of the $2^{k}$ different
> $\left(k-1\right)$-dimensional *faces* of $\mathcal{I}^{k}.$
> These faces are the sets defined by
> \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{I}_{i,\epsilon}^{k-1}= & \left\{ \left(x_{1},\dots,x_{k}\right)\in\mathcal{I}^{k}:x_{i}=\epsilon\right\} 
> \end{align*}
> for each $i=1,...,k$ and $\epsilon=0$ or $\epsilon=1$ (see Fig.
> 5.32). The $\left(i,\epsilon\right)^\text{th}$ face $\mathcal{I}_{i,\epsilon}^{k-1}$
> of $\mathcal{I}^{k}$ is the image of the unit cube $\mathcal{I}^{k-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^{k-1}$
> under the mapping $\iota_{i,\epsilon}:\mathcal{I}^{k-1}\to\mathbb{R}^{k}$
> defined by
> \begin{align*}
> \iota_{i,\epsilon}\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{k-1}\right) & =\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{i-1},\epsilon,x_{i},\dots,x_{k-1}\right).
> \end{align*}

**Is this correct? Or should it be**

\begin{align*}
\iota_{i,\epsilon}\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{k-1}\right) & =\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{i-1},\epsilon,x_{i+1},\dots,x_{k}\right)?
\end{align*}

---

Edit: the above was answered in favor of Edwards in a comment.  My curiosity about the mapping had to do with the number of permutation needed to put the inserted dimension at the end.

---

> The mapping $\iota_{i,\epsilon},$ serves as an orientation for the
> face $\mathcal{I}_{i,\epsilon}^{k-1}.$ The orientations which the
> faces (edges) of $\mathcal{I}^{2}$ receive from these mappings are
> indicated by the arrows in Fig. 5.32. We see that the positive (counterclockwise)
> orientation of $\partial\mathcal{I}^{2}$ is given by
> \begin{align*}
> \partial\mathcal{I}^{2}= & -\mathcal{I}_{1,0}^{1}+\mathcal{I}_{1,1}^{1}-\mathcal{I}_{2,1}^{2}+\mathcal{I}_{2,0}^{2}.
> \end{align*}

I'm pretty sure all the superscripts on the RHS of the above equation should be $1$, indicating a $1$-dimensional "face"; that is
\begin{align*}
\partial\mathcal{I}^{2}= & -\mathcal{I}_{1,0}^{1}+\mathcal{I}_{1,1}^{1}-\mathcal{I}_{2,1}^{1}+\mathcal{I}_{2,0}^{1}.
\end{align*}
**Is that correct?**

> If $\omega$ is a continuous 1-form, it follows that the integral
> of $\omega$ over the oriented piecewise $\mathscr{C}^{1}$ closed
> curve $\partial\mathcal{I}^{2}$ is given by
> \begin{align*}
> \int_{\partial\mathcal{I}^{2}}= & -\int_{\iota_{1,0}}\omega+\int_{\iota_{1,1}}\omega-\int_{\iota_{2,1}}\omega+\int_{\iota_{2,0}}\omega\\
> = & \sum_{i=1}^{2}\sum_{\epsilon=0,1}\left(-1\right)^{i+\epsilon}\int_{\iota_{i,\epsilon}}\omega.
> \end{align*}

Evidently, this integral is over the boundary of the unit square in the $x_1\times x_2$ coordinate plane.  That is, $\partial\mathcal{I}_{3,0}^{2}.$  Or, perhaps we could think of it as $\partial\mathcal{I}_{3,\varepsilon}^{2},$ where $\varepsilon=0\vert 1$ indicates the 2D face whose boundary we are integrating over. So I ask: **What is the domain of integration in the above equation?**

> The integral of a $\left(k-1\right)$-form $\alpha$ over $\partial\mathcal{I}^{k}$
> is defined by analogy. That is, we *define*
> \begin{align*}
> \int_{\partial\mathcal{I}^{k-1}}\alpha= & \sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{\epsilon=0,1}\left(-1\right)^{i+\epsilon}\int_{\iota_{i,\epsilon}}\alpha.
> \end{align*}
> As in Section 5, the integral over $\mathcal{I}^{k}$ of the $k$-form
> $f\mathrm{d}x_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{k}$ is defined by
> \begin{align*}
> \int_{\mathcal{I}^{k}}f\mathrm{d}x_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{k}= & \int_{\mathcal{I}^{k}}f.
> \end{align*}

##### Figure 5.32

[image]

##### My graphics

These were produced a long time ago when working with the stress tensor.  I relabeled the "blowup" image in an effort to match Edwards.

###### $\color{red}{\text{front:}x=1}
,\color{Green}{\text{ right:}y=1}
, \color{blue}{\text{ top:}z=1}, $

###### $\color{cyan}{\text{back:}x=0}
,\color{magenta}{\text{ left:}y=0}
, \bbox[black]{\color{yellow}{\text{ bottom:}z=0}}$

[image]

###### Original blowup diagram using coordinates $x,y,z$

[image]

###### Relabeled blowup diagram to match Edwards

[image]

As drawn, the positive sense of traversal is around the outward normal.  **Should the faces with $\epsilon=0$ be traversed from the inside (right thumb pointing in the positive coordinate direction), or from the outside (right thumb pointing in the direction of the outward normal)?**

---

Edit: This may actually constitute an answer.

The following modified depiction seems to move closer to understanding. If we cheat, and treat the wedge product as a cross product, we find that each surface has an outward pointing normal.  So in the case of those faces I have designated as $'+',$ the normals are the corresponding basis vectors.  In the $'-'$ cases, the outward normals are the negatives of the basis vectors.

[image]

Comment: for your first question: there is no $x_k$ component in $\cal{I}^{k-1}$.

Comment: That makes sense.